# How to avoid making multiple trips to database in Django loop?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Currently this code seems to be going to the database (Postgres) two to four times on every loop iteration. First to get (and create) the `Type`, then to get (and create) the `Component`. Is there a way to do this in fewer database trips?

`models.py`:

```
class Component(models.Model):
    long = models.TextField()
    type = models.SmallForeignKey('Type', models.CASCADE)


class Type(models.Model):
    type = models.TextField(unique=True)


class Point(models.Model):
    components = models.ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), default=[])

    def save_components(self, geocode):
        _components = []
        for c in geocode:
            ct = Type.objects.get_or_create(type=c['types'][0])
            _components.append(Component.objects.get_or_create(long=c['long_name'], type=ct).pk)
        self.components = _components
        self.save()
```

Incoming data:

```
geocode = [
    {
       "long_name" : "Luray",
       "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
    },
    {
       "long_name" : "Page County",
       "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
    },
    {
       "long_name" : "Virginia",
       "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    },
    {
       "long_name" : "United States",
       "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
    }
]
```

Comment: OK, `ct` and `component` don't come out of nowhere, they are fetched from database, how can you not hit the database and get the information?

Comment: @ShangWang Well I suppose it'd be possible to cache it locally, but that's not the question. The goal is to reduce the number of trips, possibly to 1 or 2. I suspect that would be possible given that all the information is already there at the time the first trip is made.

Comment: Why are you storing an array of primary keys, rather than using a ManyToManyField?

Comment: First, you have to query if that `Type` and `Component` exists, each costs one sql query, no doubt about that. If they don't exist, you have to create them, another 1 or 2 creation sql statements will be sent to the database. I'm not sure what do you mean `all information is already there`, don't you want to create them when if are not stored? Also as @DanielRoseman said: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've been on the fence about whether I should use an array or a through table... I already have the code written for using M2M if I ever wanted to switch back (which is even more bloated), but arrays make far more sense for the queries I want to use. Can we kindly get back on topic now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of time, Django does a decent job caching database results. If you want to have more control, you could do something like this (provided that you do not have too many types)

```
class Point(models.Model):
    components = models.ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), default=[])

    def save_components(self, geocode):
        _components = []
        _types = {t.type: t for t in Type.objects.all()}
        for c in geocode:
            ct = _types.get(c['types'][0], None)
            if not ct:
                ct = Type.objects.create(type=c['types'][0])
            _components.append(Component.objects.get_or_create(long=c['long_name'], type=ct).pk)
        self.components = _components
        self.save()
```

This should save you looking up existing types all the time. You can also try to defer creating new Types and new Components (use get() instead of get_or_create() and catch the DoesNotExist exception) and use bulk insert later in the function (here is a [doc link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/optimization/#insert-in-bulk))